# Does Delphi incremental linker correctly track distinct types?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, linker

An example with types with the same identity (TLevel and integer)

```
unit UnitType;

interface

type
  TLevel = integer;

  TObj = class
  public
    procedure Test(Level: TLevel);virtual;
  end;
```

There's another unit where another object inherits from this object (Notice integer instead of TLevel, but this is not a problem since they're not distinct)

```
unit UnitOther;

interface uses UnitType;

type
  TInhObj = class(TObj)
  public
    procedure Test(Level: integer);override;
  end;
```

Everything compiles as usual.

Now I modify TLevel type to be distinct

```
TLevel = type integer;
```

and try to compile, but everything compiles fine.

I go to UnitOther and change something unrelated (even just resave it). Now I have "declaration of Test differs from previous declaration" in unit UnitOther

Is this correct actions or a bug that was fixed in latest versions of Delphi? (mine is 5)

Comment: This would appear to be a compiler bug and it is still present in the XE2 compilers, both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Compiler bug? Wouldn't be more like an IDE bug? Compile just looks at timestamps while in this case, especially with both files open (and possibly compiled in the background), the IDE should know enough to notice the dependency?

Comment: @Marjan No, it's the compiler that decides whether or not the unit needs re-building. The IDE is not part of that decision. And it's not determined by timestamps.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok thanks, I guess my info on that was outdated, like from the eighties :-))

Comment: You shall fill a QC entry for this bug.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Delphi XE and it still behaves exactly as you described.  One workaround is to periodically run the Build event (i.e. before you commit your code).  This isn't a very eloquent solution but at least it will allow the changed typed to be detected without having to touch all the files that use it.

Comment: What's Clean? To force a re-build just do **Project | Build** from the menus.

Comment: @David, If you right click on a project in the project manager, there are three options Compile, Build, and Clean.  Clean will delete all the .dcu files associated with your project.  As a result, Compile will behave like Build.  Although, as you pointed out, its just easier to choose Build in the first place.

Comment: Ah, I had not discovered Clean. I just whack in Shift+F9 when I do things like modifying .inc files, actions that don't get noticed by the compile action.

Comment: Pity to hear, I'm used to use Build so rarely thanks to Pascal nature :)

Comment: @Maksee: hardly a problem. Delphi's single pass compile makes even builds very fast.